# Setup Webhook Receiver with signature verification - computed hash sometimes off by one character

Tags: php, webhooks, hmac, xero-api

I'm trying to develop a webhook for the Xero API for when a Contact is updated.

I managed to get past the Intent to Receive validation (eventually) thanks to the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286411/php-setup-webhook-receiver-with-signature-verification/47286696). However it doesn't always work. Sometimes, for example, the Hash I compute using:

```
$yourHash = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $webHookKey, true));
```

is off by one character - where the Web Hook Key, for example, might start with `mrj/yJ7pZKejaRrN61vAJB`, the computed hash will replace the / with a Y or some other character.

What simple stupid thing am I overlooking?

Answer (score 3):

During the setup process Xero sends several requests.  Some valid and some invalid.  The invalid ones require a `401` response header where the valid ones require a `200` response header. Are you sure that one is not one of the invalid ones?

Comment: Pretty sure the odds of the hashing algorithm being off by a single character given two different strings are astronomically low. Either way the issue seems to have resolved itself and I have everything working so it was probably something dumb I was doing.

Comment: True, if they are making it invalid by signing it with the wrong key/data. But I suspect they just randomly changing a character or two in the hash.